# share textview content with whatsapp and facebook

Tags: android, facebook, whatsapp

I am using below code and my textview links are clickable but i want to make specific button of whatsapp and facebook for sharing..i referred several article in stackoverflow but i want for textview. for webview i had earlier done and it was easy .please help /suggest for textview sharing. i dont want all buttons to open. i want after each listview one facebook and whatsapp icon. on click whatsapp should open with text to be shared

in textview i am adding below for whatsapp share but nothing happens

```
           <a rel="nofollow" href="whatsapp://send?text=एक वृद्ध दंपति को लगने लगा कि उनकी क वृद्ध दंपति को लगने लगा कि उनकी याददाश्त कमजोर हो चली है। यह सुनिश्चित करने के लिये कि उन्हें कुछ नही%0A."><span class="whatsapp">&nbsp;</span></a>
```

my java code is

tried adding this one also in java but no benefit.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        if (intent != null) {
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

main.java code here

```
         package com.hindishayari.funnywall.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;




import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import com.hindishayari.funnywall.R;
import com.hindishayari.funnywall.adapter.SwipeDownListAdapter;
import com.hindishayari.funnywall.analytics.AnalyticsApplication;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {


    // URLS for Fetching and Submitting to Funny Wall.

    private String FetchFunnyWallURL = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/AndroidFunnyWallApp/ppppppppp.php";
    private String SubmitJokeToWallURL = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/AndroidFunnyWallApp/hhhhhhhhhh.php";


    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private SwipeDownListAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> jokesList;
    private ArrayList<String> timeDateList;



    String JokeString = null;


    String []dataValues = new String[2];
    int counter = 0;


    TextView titleTextView;


    AlertDialog alertDw;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    Typeface font;


    LinearLayout adViewLayout;
    LinearLayout listViewLayout;

    private Tracker mTracker;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
        mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();


        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "HelveticaNeue-Regular.ttf");

        titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleID);
        adViewLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adViewLayoutID);
        listViewLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ListViewLinearLayout);


        titleTextView.setTypeface(font);


        dataValues[0] = "";
        dataValues[1] = "";


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

        jokesList = new ArrayList<>();
        timeDateList = new ArrayList<>();



        adapter = new SwipeDownListAdapter(this, jokesList, timeDateList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

         swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                        jokesList.clear();
                                        timeDateList.clear();

                                        new FetchFunnyWallFromServer().execute(FetchFunnyWallURL);

                                    }
                                }
        );




     /*
               This function is to refresh the List with Swipe-Down
      */

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

        jokesList.clear();
        timeDateList.clear();

        new FetchFunnyWallFromServer().execute(FetchFunnyWallURL);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }


    /*
                This function is to fetch all the jokes + dates from the server and store that into the jokesList
                timeDateLis respectively
     */

    private class FetchFunnyWallFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return FetchFunnyWall(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Sorry, We cannot retrieve credits data form the server at this moment.";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            listView.setEnabled(false);

            dataValues[0] = "";
            dataValues[1] = "";

            counter = 0;

            jokesList.clear();
            timeDateList.clear();



        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            listView.setEnabled(true);


            if (result.equals("OK")) {


                listView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Collections.reverse(jokesList);
                        Collections.reverse(timeDateList);

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                    }
                });


            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Connection Problem. Make sure that your internet is properly connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }




        }
    }

    private String FetchFunnyWall(String myurl) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        InputStream is = null;


        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
            conn.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();




            is = conn.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));


            String readlineText;


            while ((readlineText = textReader.readLine()) != null) {


                if (readlineText.length() > 0 )
                {
                    if (readlineText.equals("****")) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (readlineText.length() < 4) {
                        continue;
                    }


                    for (int i = 0; i < readlineText.length(); ++i) {
                        if (readlineText.charAt(i) == '|') {
                            ++counter;

                            continue;
                        }

                        dataValues[counter] = (dataValues[counter] + readlineText.charAt(i));
                    }


                    jokesList.add(dataValues[0]);
                    timeDateList.add(dataValues[1]);

                    counter = 0;
                    dataValues[0] = "";
                    dataValues[1] = "";


                }





            }







        }
    }




}
```

any help will be great

Comment: @alberto-fernández please help if u can its not for webview its for textview